# how to generate hyphenate url in MVC 4 .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on Visual Studio 2012 express edition to develop my website www.onlinegk.com using MVC 4. But I am facing a problem and seeking some help from my expert friend regarding this issue. The problem is  I want to make my all url in following manners:

> www.onlinegk.com/current-affairs/
>   www.onlinegk.com/employment-news/
>   www.onlinegk.com/general-knowledge/latest-whos-who

But I am not getting proper help how to implement it, means what will be the controller structure and what will be the view name etc. Please go through my routconfig.cs file as mention below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I shall be very thankful to you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for dynamic urls:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteName", 
    "controler-name/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```